# standard or not standard fonts

Tags: fonts

I use it in a text I'm writing about Physics questions, in a standardized Latex letter format, I've been looking for how to use a cursive letter in the text ALL, I believe it is more personal and less synthetic than this type of letter, which I am writing.

Looking on the site - Handwritten fonts in LaTeX / XeTeX / LuaTeX, I found a reference, about the use of cursive or handwriting, but it only works on a piece of text, I would like it to be implemented throughout the text.

Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: Try to use the command `\it` at beginning of your document.

Comment: In modern LaTeX, you’d use `\itshape`. The `\it` command is obsolete.

Comment: How than easy distinguish math variables and terms from ordinary text?

Answer (score 1):

In the modern toolchain, you can load an OpenType or TrueType handwriting font using `\newfontfamily` in `fontspec`.  If you want to make it the default, load it as `\setmainfont`.

With legacy NFSS, you can load a font package. If that does not have a package option to make the font the default, but you would like to, redefine `\familydefault`.

Answer (score 1):

See the section of [Calligraphical and Handwritten Font of LaTeX Font Cataloque](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html). The method of usage for each font is indicated on the links.

There are also fonts that look less mechanistic that default serif and sans serif fonts, but are more legible that handwritten fonts, and you can reserve the italics for the emphasized text, as usual. For me one of these fonts could be Artemisia:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2][1-5]\par\bigskip\itshape\lipsum[2][1-5] 
\end{document}
```

But just see and compare in the whole cataloque `;)`